# Where's the mistake in integrating $\operatorname{sech}$ using series?

Tags: integration

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int\frac{2dx}{e^x+e^{-x}} & = \int\frac{2e^{-x}dx}{1+e^{-2x}} \\
&= \int 2e^{-x} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^ke^{-2kx}\,dx \\
&= 2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\int  e^{-x(2k+1)}\,dx +c\\
&= -2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{ e^{-x(2k+1)}}{(2k+1)}+c
\end{split}
\end{equation} $$
Note that $\displaystyle \arctan(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$, giving
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int\frac{2\,dx}{e^x+e^{-x}} & = -2\arctan(e^{-x})+c 
\end{split}
\end{equation} $$
Wolfram says this integral is $\displaystyle\arctan\left(\tanh(\frac{x}{2})\right)$$\displaystyle=\arctan \left(\frac{1-e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}\right)=\arctan(1)+\arctan(-e^{-x})=\frac{\pi}{4}+\arctan(e^x)$

So, is  $\displaystyle -2\arctan(e^{-x})=k+\arctan(e^x)$ (if so, why?), or did I do something incorrectly? Normally I'd defer the mistake (if there is one) to my neglect for convergence, but the results are so alike that I think my method must be fundamentally correct.

Comment: That you have a correct answer cannot be an issue, since differentiating $-2\arctan(e^{-x})$ gives you the right thing.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, it boiled down to a algebraic error in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You made two mistakes:

1/ [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sech%28x%29dx) gives a factor $2$ that you missed.

2/ And this is the correct version of the difference of $\arctan$'s

$$\arctan \left(\frac{1-e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}\right)=\arctan(1)-\arctan(e^{-x})$$

Comment: The second was a typo, sorry. Yes, that helps.